# a generic error occurred in gdi+. on bitmap.save

Tags: asp.net

```
Rectangle bounds = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);

using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
        g.Dispose();
    }
  
    //bitmap.Save("test.jpg");

    Bitmap bitmap2 = new Bitmap(bitmap);                
    bitmap.Dispose();
    bitmap2.Save("~/images/it-could-be-you.jpg",
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: Why do you create `bitmap2` when you can just save `bitmap` directly? Also, you don't need to manually call `Dispose` if you've already wrapped the object in a `using` block.

Comment: i tried with itself also giving same error so then i tried another by looking some solution but same error as it is

Comment: Do you have permission to save in that folder? Also, using `~` probably isn't valid, you should use a full path.

Comment: tried with the full path and also gave permission to the folder it didnt worked